# SQLITE select mask, how to include duplicates as weel

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, mask

I have a query like this  and I would like to return all the  values in the  IN  case  with the matching number of rows.

SELECT id,name,age from USERS WHERE id IN (1,75,75);

returns

1|john|25

75|Sam|30

however what I want is

1|john|25

75|Sam|30

75|Sam|30

is such a thing possible in sql?  I would appreciate if you  guys have a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` instead:

```
select u.*
from (select 1 as id union all select 75 union all select 75) i join
     users u
     on u.id = i.id;
```

The more concise format uses `values()`:

```
with i(id) as (
      values (1), (75), (75)
)
select u.*
from i join
     users u
     on u.id = i.id;
```

Comment: the last one seems to solve the issue  however I get a syntax error  near "("  . could not figure out how

Comment: you are perfect, thank you for quick and effective solution.